# Any method allowing user to sign and save the signature?

Tags: php

I want to add a function to a dancing class booking system where a participant can sign her name (so that it records her attendance).

What I need is to save the signature in a folder like the following

```
$username=$_SESSION["currentlogin"]; 
$upload_dir="signatures/";

$filenametobesaved=$username . "_". date("F j, Y, g:i a s"). "_.jpg";
```

The current system is a database system using PHP/MySQL. Can this "signature" function be added easily ?

Answer (score 2):

On the browser, please use jquery.signaturepad to capture the signature

This is the link for the siganturepad

https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad

HTML part

```
<form id=form1 method="post" action="save1.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div  class="sigPad">
<ul class="sigNav">
<li class="drawIt"><a id="startdraw" href="#draw-it" >Start Signing</a></li>
<li class="clearButton"><a href="#clear">Clear</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="typed"></div>
<canvas  width="450" height="160" style="border:1px solid black;" id="myCanvas" ></canvas>

<input type="hidden" name="output" id=output class="output">
<input type=button value="Accept and Sign" onclick="javascript:submit1();">

</div>

<input type="hidden" name="output3" id="output3"  > 

</form>
```

Javascript Part

```
<script src="jquery.signaturepad.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.sigPad').signaturePad();
      $('#startdraw').click();
    });
  </script>

<script src="assets/json2.min.js"></script>

function submit1()
{
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
document.getElementById('output3').value = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');

if (document.getElementById('output').value == "") {
    alert("It appears that your have NOT signed !!!!");
} 

else{
document.getElementById('form1').submit();
}   

}
```

Once submitted, the PHP can simply be:

```
$upload_dir = "signatures/";  //implement this function yourself
$img = $_POST['output3'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$file = $upload_dir. $_SESSION["currentlogin"]. "_" . date("F j, Y, g:i a s") . "_". $_REQUEST["xname"].  "_.jpg";
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
```

Comment: hi did you ever get this working? i'm trying to do pretty much the same thing, capture an image and then save that image to the webserver.

i have a working canvas where the signature can be drawn, but nothing after that

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can save this in the relevant folder and can save the signature file name/path in database to track the participant for further processing.